# How are these contour integrals done?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

$$\Phi_+(\alpha) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_1}\ln\left(2 e^{-\frac{c | z| }{2}} \cosh \left(\frac{c z}{2}\right) \right) \frac{dz}{z-\alpha}$$

and

$$\Phi_-(\alpha) = - \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_2} \ln\left(2 e^{-\frac{c | z| }{2}} \cosh \left(\frac{c z}{2}\right) \right) \frac{dz}{z-\alpha}$$

where the contours $C_1$ and $C_2$ are parallel to the real line, but pass above and below the point $z=\alpha$

Here $c$ is a complex parameter.

This is called Weiner-Hopf factorization. These came when I was trying to solve an integral equation of the form $\phi(x)=f(x)+\int_0^\infty K(x-x')\phi(x)$. Where one has to factorize the Kernel into the two parts which are analytic in upper and lower half plane. According to wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Hopf_method these integrals gives such factorization.

But I am not sure how are these integrals done.

For an example if I had to factorize $\frac{1}{z^2+9}$ into $\phi_+(\alpha)+{\phi_-(\alpha)}$ such that $\phi_+$ is analytic in upper half plane and $\phi_-$ is analytic in the lower half plane.

I could use see that the function is anaytic in the strip $-3<\Im \alpha<3$ and use

$\phi_+=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\infty+d'i}^{\infty+d'i} \frac{1}{(z^2+9)(z-\alpha)}=\frac{i}{6 (\alpha +3 i)}$
where $\Im \alpha >d'>3$
and

$\phi_-=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\infty+c'i}^{\infty+d'i} \frac{1}{(z^2+9)(z-\alpha)}=\frac{-i}{6 (\alpha -3 i)}$

where $\Im\alpha<c'<3$

But in my case, I am not sure how to carry out these integrals. As I could not use the residue theorem like in the example I presented.

I am mainly looking for how to do these contour integrals.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for letting me know that. I have tried to edit my question by giving a little bit of context and adding an example.

Comment: I'm afraid that putting $|z|$ in the integrand leads to the  loss of analyticity. If you integrate by part and split your integral into $[0;\infty]$ and $[-\infty;0]$ you will get, probably, more simple integral like$\int_0^\infty\log(z-a)\frac{1}{1+\exp(cz)}$, though your area will be only half-plane.